# Creating a mesh plot from a 3D Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, 3d, mesh

I'm just getting back into MATLAB and having trouble with some fairly basic plotting. I've already searched mathworks.com...

I have some 3D array, with dimensions 200 x 2 x 11. To give some context, basically I have 11 time points, and would like to plot some 2D line for each of those.

For example, for time 1 (i.e., `myArray(:,:,1)`), I can generate some 2D plot that looks something like this:
[image]

This is just an interpolation over 200 (x,y) coordinates.

I've calculated the evolution of this line over 11 time periods, and would like to plot it in 3-dimensions. I'm trying to utilize the mesh function, which accepts arguments X,Y,Z. I'd like my time points to be on the x-axis. I'm having a little trouble with the syntax. Intuitively, I'm trying to get something like this to work:

```
for k = 1:11
  myArray(:,:,k) = [stDev, ret];
end

% mesh(X,Y,Z):
mesh(1:11, ??, ??)
```

Really the crux of the problem is I don't totally understand how to convert elements of some multidimensional array into a format that's compatible with the mesh function.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain the format of your 3D array. How do you want to plot the lines. You have `200x2x11` array and 11 time points. So do you want to plot each of the `200x2` matrix. So there will be 200 lines per time point. Another possibility is you have 2 matrices of `200x11`. So you can consider points in first matrix as `x`-coordinates and the points in the other matrix as `y`-coordinates. Which one are you looking for? Or none of these?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar I've added some detail. Let me know if you'd like more clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, a surface is parametrized like X=X(u,v), Y=Y(u,v), Z=Z(u,v), where u and v are parameters. In MATLAB terms, the parameters and the  vertical and horizontal  indices of the matrices X,Y,Z. In your case, you need X,Y,Z to be 200 by 11 matrices.

The coordinates in Y and Z are taken from your 3D array:

```
Y = squeeze(M(:,1,:));
Z = squeeze(M(:,2,:));
```

But X should be filled with the time values, which are the numbers from 1 to 11 in your case. (In general, `1:size(M,3)`.) To have these values replicated across 200 rows, use Kronecker product with
a vector of 200 1s:

```
X = kron(1:size(M,3), ones(size(M,1),1))
```

Now `mesh(X,Y,Z)` will give the desired surface.

---

For demo purpose, I used 11 curves that are all square-root graphs with different scaling.

```
M = zeros(200,2,11);
for k=1:11
    M(:,1,k) = 1:200;
    M(:,2,k) = sqrt(k*(1:200));
end
X = kron(1:size(M,3), ones(size(M,1),1));
Y = squeeze(M(:,1,:));
Z = squeeze(M(:,2,:));
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```

[image: curves]